# Bootstrap Modal popup issue in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, bootstrap-modal

[image: Screenshot of my bootstrap modal popupissue]

I called that popup in a button click like this:

```
     <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUserName"></asp:Label></a>
             </li>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I dont know why it is comming like that. I cant even close that.

I want it to be like this:

[image]

Comment: refer my screenshot to clearly understand what the hell has happened :D

Comment: The issue with dark overlay or with cutted header?

Comment: both.. it is supposed to be coming on the top of everything. i hope u understand

Comment: your code looks fine.. Also are you sure that the code you provided and the code in your project is same? Also have you checked your entire HTML to see if any div's are not closed properly..

Comment: I bet this is a `z-index` problem. Verify that your top bar z-index be lower than the popup

Answer (score 0):

**You have to write below code on close button event :**

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
$('.modal-backdrop').removeClass('modal-backdrop');
$('.fade').removeClass('fade');
$('.in').removeClass('in');
$('html, body').css({
    'overflow': 'auto',
    'height': 'auto'
});
```

**Please use below code for trigger button event :**

$.ajax({

```
        url: '/test/test?id=' + id,
        type: "Post",
        async: false,
        dataType: "html",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {  
           //Your div name where you want to show model popup data                 
            $("#YourResultDivName").empty();
            $("#YourResultDivName").html(result);

           //your button click event trigger from here for open model popup
           $("#btnhdnModelPopup").trigger('click'); 

        }
    });
```

**Check Below HTML code for model popup :**

```
<form id="ModelPopupForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <button type="button" id="btnhdnModelPopup" style="display: none;" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#divModelPopup"></button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="divModelPopup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-95" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Model Title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                           Your Data
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="btnClose" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

it will work perfectly !!

Comment: i think you didnt understand my problem clearly. Thank you anyway @Laxman Gite

Comment: You mention that you are not able to close that.

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: '/test/test?id=' + id,
            type: "Post",
            async: false,
            dataType: "html",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {                   
                $("#YourResultDivName").empty();
                $("#YourResultDivName").html(result);
                //your button id for open model popup
                $("#lblUserName").trigger('click');
                    
            }
        });

Comment: Yes @laxman but first of all it is not displaying correctly as per my need and expectations. I know how to close the popup anyway..

Comment: Then you need to check your JS and Bootstrap file references on your page.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have have works on my machine! There must be another problem outside of the code you have given. Paste this code into a blank .html document and run it then work back to what the difference is between it and yours.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>


 <li>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUserName"></asp:Label></a>
</li>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>





  </div>

</body>
</html>
```